# delete records from tables (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables:

```
PERSON
-ID_PERSON
-NAME
-SURNAME

PERSON_ADDRESS
-ID_PERSON
-ID_ADDRESS

ADDRESS
-ID_ADDRESS
-NR_LOCAL
-NR_HOME
-PLACE
```

I would like delete all records with ADRESS table where id_person=1

My query ( in oracle )

```
DELETE * FROM address INNER JOIN person_addres ON
address.id_address=person_addres.id_address 
WHERE person_addres.id_person=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case `person` and `address` tables have many-to-many relationship. This means that one person is able to have multiple addresses and one address at the same time may belong to multiple persons. You want to delete address of a particular person and you want to delete it from the `address` table. Let's consider the following situation. Person with ID=1 has an Address with ID=2 according to the `person_address` table and person with ID = 2 has the same address(ID=2). What would have happened if you had deleted address records related to person #1 (ID = 1)? Person #2 would be left without an address or you would get `integrity constraint violated` (depending on your `on delete` option).

To delete address of a particular persons leave other persons address intact it's better to delete records from `person_address` table not the `address`. And delete record from `address` table only if there are no persons to whom that address was assigned.

To delete all "addresses" (all records from `person_address` table) of a particular person (person that has ID = 1 in this case) you can use the following SQL.

```
delete 
  from (select q.id_person
          from address t
          join person_address q
            on (q.id_address = t.id_address)
        ) x
  where x.id_person = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I would like delete all records with ADRESS table where id_person=1"

You have a many-to-many relationship between Person and Address.  This means you will delete Address records which are used by Persons where `id_person != 1`.  Is that what you really want to do?

Presuming that is the case, you need to do this in three steps:

1. get all the values of  `id_address` in `person_address` where `id_person=1`
2. delete all the matched records in `person_address`
3. delete all the matched records in `address`

In Oracle you can do this in two statements, using bulk actions and the predefined ODCINUMBERLIST collection (I hope your IDs are numeric).

```
declare
    addr_nt ODCINUMBERLIST;
begin
    delete from person_address
    where id_person=1
    returning id_address bulk collect into addr_nt;

    forall i in addr_nt.first..addr_nt.last
        delete from address
        where addr_id = addr_nt(i);
 end;
```

---

Of course, if you don't have foreign keys defined between your tables you can follow the other suggestions and blithely just delete from the `address` table.  Your data will be corrupt and unreliable but that's the price of not enforcing relational integrity.

Comment: Thanks I understand however I write in SQL not PL/SQL and I this command will copy to Acces MS Because I am coding application databse. I am interesting simple solve :) Help :)

Comment: You should specify *all* your requirements in your question, rather than adding them later in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The table person_address **should** have foreign key constraints to the tables person and address.
To gracefully delete a person, consider using this procedure.

Although I would personally never delete person details, but rather have column in the table person with the status of the person (Active or Inactive for example).

```
create or replace procedure remove_person(p_id_person in person.id_person%type )
is
begin
    delete from person where id_person = p_id_person;
    delete from address where id_address in (select id_address from person_address where id_person = p_id_person);
    delete from person_address where id_person = p_id_person;

-- no exception handling, I want to know when this fails
end;
```

Then use like this:

```
begin
  remove_person(1);
end;
```

Comment: Personally I think you're wrong.  Logical deletion introduces the potential for bugs, it complicates queries and relational integrity and may even cause performance issues.  The right approach is to physcally delete the PERSON, ADDRESS whatever  records and use an audit or history table to remember the details.

Comment: Also, there is no stated requirement to delete the PERSON records.  Also your code will fail if there is more than one ADDRESS per PERSON_ID, which given that the model implements a M:N relationship isa highly likely scenario.

Comment: Good points. I adjusted my procedure to take the M:N relationship into account. Was a bit too quick there. ;)
The logical deletion has served me well, but an audit or history table will work just as fine. A matter of taste imo. (Not that I expect the TS to use this anyway, because he doesn't seem to work on a real database.)

Comment: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_OSOBKAAA) violated - child record found
02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"
*Cause:    attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign
           dependency.
*Action:   delete dependencies first then parent or disable constraint.                                                          becasue id_person exist in person_addres........

Comment: Ok below slove is ok, working in acces, why not working in oracle? Where I am commiting error?

Comment: @dexter90 - as I have pointed out *several times* in this thread (and been downvoted for my pains), the other proposed solutions won't work if you have foreign keys in place and will leave your database in a corrupt state if you don't have them.  Anyway, obviously you do have integrity constraints in your Oracle database and that's why this code is hurling.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a sub select - sorry my Oracle is rusty:

```
DELETE * FROM address WHERE id_address IN (SELECT id_address FROM person_address WHERE id_person = 1)
```

Comment: I think you have to remove `*`

Comment: Thanks, I solve problem this method ( documenaction ), THANKS.

Comment: OK, working My solve:   delete  from person_addres where id_person = 1;

delete from address where id_address <> ( select id_address from person_address )

Comment: @dexter90 - You should post your "solution" as an answer so we can vote and comment on it properly.  What you have coded will delete *any address* which is not associated with a person: that is a business rule you may not wish to apply.  Also you still have hanging `person_address` records (where `person_id != 1` but whose `address` records you have deleted).

Answer (score -1):

First select the address id from person address where person_id=1 and then remove the row from address where address i is equal to the result of previous query. That's all

```
DELETE * FROM ADDRESS WHERE ID_ADDRESS IN ( SELECT ID_ADDRESS FROM PERSON_ADDRESS WHERE ID_PERSON='1')
```

Comment: delete  from ( select * from address aa JOIN person_address oa ON aa.id_adres=oa.id_adres WHERE oa.id_person =1)

delete records with table person_address :(